# How can I align subfigures and captions?

Tags: captions

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{images/topologia_2_platos.png}
\caption{Topología de 2 platos}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{images/topologia_3_platos.png}
\caption{Topología de 3 platos}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Topologías de los encoders capactivos rotativos}
\label{fig:topologias_encoders_capacitivos}
\end{figure}
```

I get this:

[image: Result]

First used image:

[image: First image]

Second used image:

[image: Second image]

Comment: Does using `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}` help?

Comment: Subfigures (from subcaption) are basically minipages with captions.  The default is to center the contents [c].  [t] (the first baseline) is the bottom of the image, whilc [b] (last baseline) is either the top or bottom of the caption (I forget which).

Comment: BTW, it the left image is lower, it must have a lot of white space above it.

Comment: @leandriis yes, by varying 0.48 to another number it makes the subfigure bigger or smaller

Comment: and I don't know what [b] really does

Comment: It usually works fine with the `subfloatrow` environment from the `floatrow`  package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming, that at both your picture is equal (zero) white space and that the haven't equal height, than the following solution should work for you (it consider some comments below question):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{images/topologia_2_platos.png}
\caption{Topología de 2 platos}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}%{images/topologia_3_platos.png}
\caption{Topología de 3 platos}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Topologías de los encoders capactivos rotativos}
\label{fig:topologias_encoders_capacitivos}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Comment: @el_maxx, what didn't work? Please, be more specific. Proposed solution works (as it is) for sure.

Comment: See what I edited on my post

Comment: @el_maxx, what you got? I don't see anything what you got( (my crystal ball is out of order ;-) )

Comment: Please see the description, I just changed it.

Comment: @el_maxx, you should consider all comments which you receive ... Your images have white space above/below . To see this, insert them in `\fbox{<image>}, i.e. include them as `\fbox{\includegraphics{images/topologia_3_platos.png}}`. Try to remove white spaces between frame and images with some program for editing images.